# Get Modified date of current page in Site Pages using SPServices

Tags: sharepoint-server, spservices

Using embedded script on a page from "Site Pages", I want to display the Modified date at the bottom of the page (I also want to display a custom column called "Page Owner", but I have figured out how to get that generically).

I can get the info about ALL of the pages in Site Pages, my challenge is to return info just for the page that is currently displayed.

How do I sense the current page and display just its info?

Here is the code that works for all pages:

```
   function getData() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "Site Pages",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Page_x0020_Owner'/>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Modified'/>" +
            "</ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_LinkFilename") +
                    ' // ' + $(this).attr("ows_Modified") + 
                    ' // ' + $(this).attr("ows_Page_x0020_Owner") + "</li>";
                $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following scripts in each page. It will display the current page info.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get the id of the current page
    var pageId = _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId;
    getData(pageId);
});

  function getData(pageId) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "Site Pages",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Author'/>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Modified'/>" +
            "</ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>" + pageId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_LinkFilename") +
                    ' // ' + $(this).attr("ows_Modified") + 
                    ' // ' + $(this).attr("ows_Author") + "</li>";
                $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
```